# "will be ..." vs. "are presented in section ..." (tenses in scientific writing)

Tags: tenses, science

I'm writing my bachelor thesis in English in a German language environment so I was unable to get help from my supervisor on language related questions (neither of the languages is my first language). I am confused which tense should I be using when referring to sections of the thesis:

> Details are presented in Section 5.1. (present)

vs.

> Details will be presented in Section 5.1 (future)

It is obvious that the second option can only be used when the section describing these details is succeeding the current one and for consistency reasons, I should probably go for the first version (because I reefer to previous sections too) to avoid using past tense.

However, Google returns slightly more hits for the second option (44 vs. 36 millions). Which tense should I use when referring to other sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with 'are presented'. Another way of looking at this is that 'are presented' means the details are there, you can turn/scroll to the section and see them there. While 'will be presented' could mean once I've added the details that is where they will be.